# Gulp-bower throws error 'calling transform done when ws.length != 0'

Tags: gulp, bower

During Gulp build I sometimes get the error 'calling transform done when ws.length != 0' and the stack traces gives path node_modules\gulp-bower\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_transform.js:204
I am not able to track the source of the error in build.js. How to find the code from where it is called upon?